# Printing a line in a certain percentile of a larg text file

Tags: sed, tail, head, wc

I am looking for a single line command to print a line in a certain percentile of a large text file. My preferred solution is something based on sed, wc -l, and/or head/tail as I already know how to do that with awk and wc -l.  To make it more clear, if my file has 1K lines of text, I need to print for example the (95%*1K)th line of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash:

```
head -`echo scale=0\;$(cat file|wc -l)\*95/100 | bc -l` file | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
head -`wc -l file | awk '{print(int(0.95*$1))}'` file | tail -n 1
```